# pointer-to-const conversion in C

Tags: c, constants

The following code compiles without warning on GCC but gives a warning in Visual Studio 2005.

```
const void * x = 0;
char * const * p = x;
```

x points to a constant object of unknown type, and p points to a constant pointer to char. Why should the assignment to p result in a warning?

Again, this is C, not C++. Thanks.

Comment: could you add the warning message?

Comment: Agree with Etan: this question would have been much clearer if the warning message was stated. It is:

warning C4090: 'initializing' : different 'const' qualifiers

Comment: My VS2005 (configured to C++) actually returns an error in this case:

'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const void *' to 'char *const *'. 
Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

Comment: Compiling the code as C should give you the C4090 warning.

Comment: Some compilers issue warnings even with `void *` conversions when they see that the pointers appear to have different level of indirection. This might be the reason fro MSVC++ warning. Otherwise, there's no problems with this code.

Comment: Do you get a warning without the `const`s?

Answer (score 5):

It happens because when you make a pointer of one type point to another type, **sometimes it is done unintentionally** (bug), so the compiler warns you about it.

So, in order to tell the compiler that you actually intent to do it, you have to do explicit casting, like this:

```
        const void * x = 0;
        char * const * p = (char * const * )x;
```

---

P.S. At the first place I wrote "*most of the times* is done unintentionally", but AndreyT made me reconsider it when he rightfully said that void * exists specifically for that purpose.

Comment: this is a c++-style "clobber the type" approach. the correct solution is different in C.

Comment: `void *` exists specifically for that purpose. Issuing warnings on that would be completely useless. The only justification for a warning in this case might be the apparent different level of indirection in pointers, not just because they point to different types.

Answer (score 3):

The C code is valid and a conforming compiler shouldn't warn as `const` ness is correctly preserved and conversion of `void *` to any pointer type (function pointers aside) is implicit.

A C++ compiler is supposed to warn about the implicit conversion, but a warning about discarding the `const` qualifier is wrong and should be considered a compiler bug.

Answer (score 0):

What if `x` would point to, say, a `struct Thing` as opposed to a `char`? In that case, you'd be doing something with unspecified behavior. GCC tends to let you do this because it assumes that you're smart enough not to shoot yourself in the foot, but there is good reason for the warning.

Comment: gcc let's you do this because the standard says `void *` can be converted to any pointer type (function-pointers aside) implicitly

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the following from right to left. 
char * const * p = x;

For Example:
P points to a const pointer of type char.

Answer (score 0):

```
const void * x = 0;
char * const * p = x;
```

At first I assumed you meant to take the address of x and wrote the code for that. Then I decided that x points to a pointer to char []. Both anyway, and it's still quite confusing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char s [] = "Hello World!";
        const void * x = s;
        const char * const * const p = (const char * const *)&x;
        printf("%s\n", *p);
/* won't compile
        *p++;      // increments x to point to 'e'
        (**p)++;   // increments 'H' to 'I'
*/
        const char * y = s;
        x = &y;
        const char * const * const q = x;
        printf("%s\n", *q);
/* won't compile
        *q++;
        (**q)++;
*/
        return 0;
}
```

The extra `const` before the `char` in the declaration of `p` prevents `(**p)++` from compiling. However, the added `const` before the declaration of `q` (in GCC) shadows `warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer` with `error: increment of read-only location ‘**q’` for `(**q)++`. Hope that helps, it has helped me a little :-)

Answer (score -2):

```
warning C4090: 'initializing' : different 'const' qualifiers
```

You cannot cast `const void` to `char *const` or even `char *`. By dereferencing `p`, you can now modify `*(char *)(*x)`. This is a little known subtlety about pointers in C.

A working type for `p` would be:

```
char const **p = x;
```

And yes, I put `const` on the right like a man.

Comment: the warning is wrong as `const` ness is preserved (remember to read declarations inside-out and that `const void` is the same as `void const`)

Comment: nope. ran this on a C compiler. the problem is stuffing the const void into char *const. by dereffing p you can now modify x.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. There's no way to modify `x` through `p`. We never take the address of `x` anywhere in the code.